# How to make A2C learn for reward that does not go negative at all?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have a custom environment which is a simulation of a fermentation process. The fermentation can run for 1200 steps only (length of experiment). There are 2 termination steps for my environment which is

1. at the end of experiment ie. `experiment_time_steps >=1200`
2. as soon as the product concentration starts decreasing.

when I run my custom environment on A2C using `model.learn(total_timesteps = 10,000)` I observe the environment reset() while total_timesteps counter keeps increasing.
Ex.

```
total_timesteps = 1 , experiement_time_steps = 1 , reward = 10 
total_timesteps = 2 , experiement_time_steps = 2 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 3 , experiement_time_steps = 3 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 4 , experiement_time_steps = 4 , reward = 10
**** product declined 
total reward 40 (I assume they add each steps() reward that is returned)
reset()
total_timesteps = 5 , experiement_time_steps = 1 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 6 , experiement_time_steps = 2 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 7 , experiement_time_steps = 3 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 8 , experiement_time_steps = 4 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 9 , experiement_time_steps = 5 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 10 , experiement_time_steps = 6 , reward = 10
total_timesteps = 11 , experiement_time_steps = 7 , reward = 10
product declined
total_reward = 70
reset()
```

Because my termination due to enzyme decline is completely random, it sometimes runs for 200 times (the step function) and the reward value is around 500 but sometimes it runs only for 100 iterations because the actions taken caused the product to decline early and my reward value is 50.

So My plot for ep_mean(tensorboard) is random lines going up and down which is not something I am expecting because I want to see the model learning and the ep mean going up. Is there a way I can discard the low ep_mean runs and plot only for high rewards/increasing rewards?

Ex. out of 10,000 timesteps my environment resets 5 times due to decline in product. so I get 5 different reward values at the end like below

```
total_timesteps = 1 - 500 , reward = 700
total_timesteps = 500-700 , reward = 200
total_timesteps = 700-4000, reward = 1000
total_timesteps = 4001-9000 reward = 100
total_timesteps = 9001-10000, reward = 10
```

when this is plotted I get a graph that is fluctuating.

So, Basically my A2C model is not learning right? Because before each reset the reward function is giving out different values(high and low but +ve).

How can I make my model learn in such a situation?